# Gnosis Safe - Connect to site that needs to connect using MetaMask and not WalletConnect

Tags: metamask, multisignature, gnosis, gnosis-safe

I have a multi-sig wallet created and in use.  It requires 2 of 4 signatures and all seems to be working just fine with it.

I now need to interact with a website (https://vault.daomaker.com/#/) to connect the wallet with it, but the site only has MetaMask as an option and not WalletConnect.

Is there a way to make the two connect? Possibly using an app on the multi-sig contract, or some way to add it into a MetaMask account list?

Comment: did you find the answer for this i have the same problem ?

Answer (score 2):

Maker vaults (https://oasis.app/) now supports Walletconnect and is also a dedicated Gnosis Safe App.

You should be able to connect your Gnosis Safe to the app by accessing the 'Apps' tab in https://gnosis-safe.io/app and clicking into the 'Oasis Borrow' app.

Alternatively, you can use Walletconnect - https://help.gnosis-safe.io/en/articles/4356253-walletconnect-safe-app.

Comment: Thanks!  Didn't know they had added WalletConnect.... Appreciate the update